# How to do updates on running installations?

Tags: concourse

Given a running concourse setup (using binaries) with multiple workers and two concourse web instances, how should a version update be done so that it doesn't disrupt the existing pipelines and running jobs?

Right now I've tried:

1. Retire worker (wait until it disappears from the worker list)
2. Stop worker
3. Update worker binary
4. Remove everything in the worker dir
5. Start worker

Is this the "recommended" way? Can I immediately stop the worker after executing the `retire-worker` command?

Comment: Personally I'd wish workers would auto update from the web server similiar to how fly sync works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `BOSH` it should be as simple as uploading the new bosh deployments for `garden` and `concourse` and update the concourse manifest and simply do a Bosh deploy e.g. `bosh -e aws deploy -d concoursedep manifest.yml`